# Symmetric linear least-squares solution

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, quadratic-programming, least-squares

Given tall matrices $A$ and $Y$ and the following overdetermined linear system in square matrix $X$

$$AX=Y$$

is there an explicit formula for the least-squares solution if $X$ is constrained to be symmetric?

Comment: Presumably, given symmetry constraint, $X$ and $Y$ are square matrices, in which case  $X=A^+Y$ is not the least squares solution (of vec'd problem, or equivalently, minimizing Frobenius norm of $X - Y$). Please clarify.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone $X$ is square but $A$ and $Y$ are tall.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have said $Y$ square. But my point about $X=A^+Y$ not being the solution in the absence of symmetry requirement still stands. That formula assumes $X$ and $Y$ are column vectors.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I see. That part isn't essential to the question so I just removed it.

Comment: I don't know of any explicit formula (but not saying it doesn't exist). But it can be readily formulated and numerically solved as a convex Quadratic Programming (QP) or Second Order Cone Problem (SOCP).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that $A$ is onto, so that $H:=A^TA$ is positive definite. Minimizing $\|AX-Y\|_F^2$ in Frobenius norm (the least square) among symmetric matrices $X$ yields the optimality condition that
$$\langle AS,AX-Y\rangle=0$$
for every symmetric $S$. This amounts to saying that $A^T(AX-Y)$ is skew-symmetric. In other words, $X$ is the solution of the Lyapunov equation
$$HX+XH=A^TY+Y^TA=:K.$$
The explicit formula is
$$X=\int_0^\infty e^{-tH}Ke^{-tH}dt.$$

Comment: Is (numerical) evaluation of that integral more difficult than numerically solving the convex  Quadratic Programming  (QP) or Second Order Cone Problem (SOCP) of minimizing Frobenius norm (or its square) subject to constraint $X = X^T$?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Why compute the integral? Isn't the Lyapunov equation a system of linear equations? Why not use Gaussian elimination?

Comment: Prof. Serre, is it still a Lyapunov equation without information on the positive definiteness of (symmetric) matrix $K$?

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo My bad. You are correct.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo. $K$ does not need to be positive, but $H$ needs to. Actually, the semi-definite case (for $H$) reduces to the positive definite one, by using the orthogonal projection $\Pi$ onto the subspace $(\ker A)^\bot$. Then you must replace $Y$ by $\Pi Y$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo. One does not have any information about $K$, besides it is symmetric. Change $Y$ into $-Y$ and $K$ becomes $-K$.

Answer (score 3):

Complementing Denis Serre's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/340001/91764) and rephrasing the original problem slightly, given tall matrices $\rm A$ and $\rm B$, we have the following quadratic program in square matrix $\rm X$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm A \mathrm X - \mathrm B \|_{\text F}^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm X = \mathrm X^\top\end{array}$$

We define the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal L (\mathrm X, \Lambda) := \| \mathrm A \mathrm X - \mathrm B \|_{\text F}^2 + \langle \Lambda, \mathrm X - \mathrm X^\top \rangle$$

Differentiating the Lagrangian with respect to $\mathrm X$ and $\Lambda$ and finding where the derivatives vanish, we obtain the following system of linear matrix equations

$$\begin{aligned} 2 \mathrm A^\top \left( \mathrm A \mathrm X - \mathrm B \right) + \Lambda - \Lambda^\top &= \mathrm O\\ \mathrm X - \mathrm X^\top &= \mathrm O \end{aligned}$$

which can be rewritten as follows

$$\begin{aligned} \mathrm A^\top \left( \mathrm A \mathrm X - \mathrm B \right) &= -\frac12 \left( \Lambda - \Lambda^\top \right)\\ \mathrm X &= \mathrm X^\top\end{aligned}$$

From the 1st matrix equation, we conclude that matrix $\mathrm A^\top \left( \mathrm A \mathrm X - \mathrm B \right)$ is **skew-symmetric**, i.e.,

$$\left( \mathrm A^\top \left( \mathrm A \mathrm X - \mathrm B \right) \right)^\top = -\mathrm A^\top \left( \mathrm A \mathrm X - \mathrm B \right)$$

which can be rewritten as the following [Lyapunov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation)-like linear matrix equation in symmetric matrix $\rm X$

$$\boxed{ \mathrm X \left( \mathrm A^\top \mathrm A \right) + \left( \mathrm A^\top \mathrm A \right) \mathrm X = \mathrm A^\top \mathrm B + \mathrm B^\top \mathrm A }$$

Half-[vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) both sides of the matrix equation above, we obtain a system of linear equations in the entries of $\rm X$ not in the lower triangular

$$\left( \mathrm A^\top \mathrm A \oplus \mathrm A^\top \mathrm A \right) \mathrm D \, \mbox{vech} (\mathrm X) = \mathrm D \, \mbox{vech} \left( \mathrm A^\top \mathrm B + \mathrm B^\top \mathrm A \right)$$

where $\oplus$ denotes the [Kronecker sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerSum.html) and $\rm D$ is a (tall) [duplication matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplication_and_elimination_matrices). Assuming invertibility, the least-squares solution could be written as follows

$$\hat{\mathrm X} := \mbox{vech}^{-1} \left( \mathrm L \left( \mathrm A^\top \mathrm A \oplus \mathrm A^\top \mathrm A \right)^{-1} \mathrm D \, \mbox{vech} \left( \mathrm A^\top \mathrm B + \mathrm B^\top \mathrm A \right) \right)$$

where $\rm L$ is a (fat) [elimination matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplication_and_elimination_matrices).